# Append & detach same files in c#

Tags: c#, .net, filestream

I want to append 2 files and I want to detach the same files?
It's that possible in c#? I did some codes to append its possible but detach I don't know. 
Any one know to do that please help .thanks,

Comment: i think, you need to split the file. 
May be this will help you. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546143.aspx

Comment: @Maverick no , I know to split files and join, but my need is to combine files for eg,"hello.exe" and hello.txt in to one file as twohello.hello.and I want to detach same files hello.exe and hello.txt from twohello.hello This what I want.

Comment: There is no such term as *detach file* in `c#`, nor in `.net` or `filestream`. You either have to use proper tag or put very good explanation of what you mean. Question and previous comment doesn't makes it any clear. *Combine* exe-file and txt-file into what? *Split* is the best term to do opposite operation to *append*, yet you disagree. So what exactly you want?

Comment: @Sinatr I want to join two files like in zip files and should be able to undo it. I hope that makes it clear.

Comment: Yes, totally. You have to implement own *container* file format (with data compression if you want). This way you can identify container and *detach* (correct word - extract) files from it.

Comment: @Sinatr can you show me example ?

Answer (score 0):

To combine files into one and then extract files back you will need to define a file format and store information about file sizes, names, compression method, etc.

Combining exe- and txt-files into one won't work without extra info.

One easy way is to define *separator*, which will tell you when one file is finished and another one is started (possibly first few bytes after separator will be file name, then `0x00` and actual data).

Another way is to use *header*, where you keep all info. Header is usually consist of *signature* and then some data structures (file name, size) so that you can find file related data after reading just header.

Probably easiest for you to *combine* file would be to actually zip them. See and search for [`ZipAchieve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx) (.net 4.5).